# Registry Shell Extension - Bold MuiVERB Text Flag

Tags: windows-registry, context-menu, flag

**Not a strictly programming question, but I've tried different approaches.**

I have a context menu with the following flags:

- `AppliesTo` = `System.FileExtension:=.mp4`
- `Icon` = `WMPLoc.dll,-503`
- **`MuiVERB` = `Otwórz`**
- `MultiSelectModel` = `Document`

---

### Is there a registry string flag that could allow me to make bold text? (`MuiVerb` / `@`)

...or some handler like `MuiVerb` = `System.BoldString("Otwórz")`, because I have no idea.

**This would be the best idea, especially if I wanted to change the string to something else - `Otwórz` is an polish translation for `Open`.**

I was looking on [*Context Menu Handlers*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers#customizing-a-shortcut-menu-using-static-verbs) on Microsoft Learn page, and I found:

> For canonical verbs, such as **Open** and **Print**, you can omit the display string because the system automatically displays a properly localized string.
> *For noncanonical verbs, if you omit the display string, the verb string is displayed.*

But I don't know how to implement this - besides the ugly look of this solution leading to create another registry keys just to have bold text is absurd. <s>Furthermore, I'm lazy.</s>

| How does it look | My approach |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

###### ⚠️ Please notice that the `Otwórz` text **IS NOT** at the beggining of the explorer menu.

Comment: I don't think you can make such text bold.